# How to fit the view to the size of the object? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building my first game in Android Studio. Right now, dots fall from the top of the screen down to the bottom. For some reason, in Layout Inspector the view of each dot is the entire screen even though the dots are comparatively small. This negatively affects the game since when a user presses anywhere on the screen, it deletes the most recently created dot rather than the one pressed. I want to get the dot's view to match the size of the actual dots without effecting other functionality.

Dot.kt

```
class Dot(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, private var dotColor: Int, private var xPos: Int, private var yPos: Int) : View(context, attrs) {
        private var isMatching: Boolean = false
        private var dotIsPressed: Boolean = false
        private var isDestroyed: Boolean = false
        private lateinit var mHandler: Handler
        private lateinit var runnable: Runnable

        init {
                this.isPressed = false
                this.isDestroyed = false
                mHandler = Handler()
                runnable = object : Runnable {
                        override fun run() {
                                moveDown()
                                invalidate()
                                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 20)
                        }
                }
                val random = Random()
                xPos = random.nextInt(context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels)
                startFalling()
                startDrawing()
        }

        // other methods

        fun getDotColor() = dotColor

        fun getXPos() = xPos

        fun getYPos() = yPos

        fun isMatching() = isMatching

        fun setMatching(matching: Boolean) {
                this.isMatching = matching
        }

        fun dotIsPressed() = dotIsPressed

        override fun setPressed(pressed: Boolean) {
                this.dotIsPressed = pressed
        }

        fun isDestroyed() = isDestroyed

        fun setDestroyed(destroyed: Boolean) {
                this.isDestroyed = destroyed
        }

        fun moveDown() {
                // code to move the dot down the screen
                yPos += 10
        }

        fun checkCollision(line: Line) {
                // check if dot is colliding with line
                // if yes, check if dot is matching or not
                // update the dot state accordingly
        }

        fun startFalling() {
                mHandler.post(runnable)
        }

        fun startDrawing() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
                        override fun run() {
                                invalidate()
                                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500)
                        }
                }, 500)
        }

        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
                super.onDraw(canvas)
                if (!isDestroyed) {
                        val paint = Paint().apply {
                                color = dotColor
                        }
                        canvas?.drawCircle(xPos.toFloat(), yPos.toFloat(), 30f, paint)
                }
        }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var score = 0
    private lateinit var scoreCounter: TextView
    private val dots = mutableListOf<Dot>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        createLine(Color.RED, 5000)
        scoreCounter = TextView(this)
        scoreCounter.text = score.toString()
        scoreCounter.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout)
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
        val params = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        params.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
        params.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
        scoreCounter.layoutParams = params
        layout.addView(scoreCounter)

        val dotColors = intArrayOf(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW)
        val random = Random()
        val handler = Handler()
        val runnable = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                val dotColor = dotColors[random.nextInt(dotColors.size)]
                createAndAddDot(0, 0, dotColor)
                handler.postDelayed(this, 500)
            }
        }
        handler.post(runnable)
    }

    fun updateScore(increment: Int) {
        score += increment
        scoreCounter.text = score.toString()
    }


    fun createAndAddDot(x: Int, y: Int, color: Int) {
        Log.d("Dot", "createAndAddDot called")
        val dot = Dot(this, null, color, x, y)
        val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout)
        layout.addView(dot)
        dots.add(dot)

        dot.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                val dotToRemove = dots.find { it == view }
                dotToRemove?.let {
                    layout.removeView(it)
                    dots.remove(it)
                    updateScore(1)
                    view.performClick()
                }
            }
            true
        }
    }

    fun createLine(color: Int, interval: Int) {
        Log.d("Line", "createLine called")
        val line = Line(color, interval)
        val lineView = Line.LineView(this, null, line)
        val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout)
        if (layout == null) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Layout not found")
        }
        layout.addView(lineView)
        val params = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(2000, 350)
        lineView.layoutParams = params
        params.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
        params.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
        params.endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
        params.bottomMargin = (0.1 * layout.height).toInt()
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Your view here -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Guideline set to 10% from the bottom -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried changing the view size with
`override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) { super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec) val diameter = 40 // or any other desired diameter for the dots setMeasuredDimension(diameter, diameter) }`

That made the view size a square stuck in the top left corner. As I played around with it, I could only get dots to show in that small window in the top corner rather than moving down the screen from different starting x-positions

Answer (score 0):

Your custom view isn't a dot, it's a large display area that draws a dot *somewhere inside it* and animates its position. In `onDraw` you're drawing a circle at `xPos` (a random point on the screen width via `displayMetrics.widthPixels`) and `yPos` (an increasing value which moves the dot down the view).

There are two typical approaches to things like this:

- use simple views like `ImageView`s. Let the containing `Activity` or `Fragment` add them to a container and control their position, maybe using the View Animation system. Handle player interaction by giving them click listeners and let the view system work out what's been clicked.
- create a custom view that acts as the game area. Let that custom view control the game state (what dots exist, where they currently are) and draw that state in `onDraw`. Handle touch events on the view, and work out if those touches coincide with a dot (by comparing to the current game state).

What you're doing is sort of a combination of the two with none of the advantages that either approach gives on its own. You have multiple equally-sized "game field" views stacked on top of each other, so any clicks will be consumed by the top one, because you're clicking the entire view itself. And because your custom view fills the whole area, you can't move it around with basic view properties to control where the dot is - you have to write the logic to draw the view and animate its contents.

---

You *could* implement some code that handles the clicks and decides whether the view consumes it (because it intersects a dot) or passes it on to the next view in the stack, but that's a lot of work and you still have all your logic split between the Activity/Fragment and the custom view itself.

I think it would be way easier to just pick one approach - either use `ImageView`s sized to the dot you want and let the view system handle the interaction, or make a view that runs the game internally. Personally I'd go with the latter (you'll find it a lot easier to handle dots going out of bounds, get better performance, more control over the look and interaction etc, no need to cancel `Runnable`s) but it's up to you!